# Reading from register of Allwinner H3 ARM processor

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, arm, hardware

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>


static void foo(void){
    volatile  uint32_t *temp_addr;
    temp_addr = (uint32_t*)(0x01C20C00);
    *temp_addr =0;
}
int main(){
    tinit();

};
```

It compiles but returns `Segmentation fault` message as a result. I just want to reset all bits in register `0x01c200c00`.

[image]

Comment: What's at `0x01C20C00`?

Comment: I've just added part of datasheet.

Comment: Right. But you're running this from the Linux userspace. You're getting the `Segmentation fault` because that address is not mapped into the process' memory.

Comment: i am just compiling this program on terminal of my device which contains exactly this processor. Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: As an ordinary user you don't have access to hardware, AFAIK. That's what @dragosht said.

Comment: Think of it this way, you have *kernel-space* and *user-space* where *kernel-space* is protected from anything that happens in *user-space*. This is a security feature that protects the kernel from any errant or malicious *user-space* processes. (now there are mechanism for privilege elevation that allow *user-space* code to interact with *kernel-space* processes). You are trying to access the *kernel-space* `TIMER` address directly bypassing all the *kernel-space* protections. That won't work, (if it did, there would be no such thing as separation between *kernel-space* and *user-space*)

Comment: The kernel and runtime library likely provide the ability to interact with that timer properly by including a proper header and using one of the timer functions provided. Looking up the address of the timer and attempting to access it directly likely fails for the reasons outlined above. Type `apropos timer` in your console window for a list of available timer functions to look at : `getitimer, settimer, timer_create, ...`

Comment: you would need to write a kernel driver, use mmap() or if tools/libraries are already available for that processor/platform use those (first as they would interfere with anything else you try).

Comment: What is exactly your ultimate goal ? If you want to experiment at a low level with the H3 hardware for learning purpose, running bare-metal programs from u-boot, uploaded using the `loadb` command , or directly uploaded to the H3 using USB and the [sunxi-fel](https://linux-sunxi.org/FEL/USBBoot) tool is a way to go. If you want to learn on how to interface/use the H3 hardware in Linux, you were already answered in the comments above, and  you can looking at the Linux H3 timer driver code [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/clocksource/timer-sun4i.c).

Comment: You may find reading at least chapter 1 of [Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) of interest if you want to learn more on hardware abstraction in Linux. The book does cover Linux 2.6.x, but the basic concepts are  still valid - I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Your program does not work because 0x01C20C00 is a physical address, but your program uses virtual addresses. For experimentation, you can access GPIO, timers, or other peripherals without writing a kernel driver. For this, you need to create a memory mapping, like this:

```
#define ALLWINNER_TIMER_BASE 0x01C20C00

struct allwinner_timer
{
  volatile uint32_t IRQ_EN_REG;
  // add other registers from the datasheet, or find a kernel driver source with these definitions
};

int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
struct allwinner_timer *t = (struct allwinner_timer *)mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, ALLWINNER_TIMER_BASE);
// TODO: check for errors
t->IRQ_EN_REG = 0;
```

Note that:

- It may not work if kernel restricts access to `/dev/mem`. This can be found out by looking at kernel options, e.g. CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM and with `dmesg`;
- It has to run under superuser, obviously;
- Your code may interfere with other parts of the system, e.g. kernel drivers accessing the same peripheral, leading to unpredictable results.